# Laravel 5 login authenication issue

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, authentication, laravel-5

I have an issue with user authentication. I can create a new user and use laravel's `Hash::make` command to encrypt the password which all appears to be working correctly see database record below :

[image]

Now for the login script. I did a dump die on the `$input` and confirmed it has the post data from the login form inside it.

Code :

```
   public function CheckLogin()
{
    $input = Request::all();

    // create our user data for the authentication
    $userdata = array(
        'Email'     => $input['email'],
        'Password'  => $input['password']
    );

    // attempt to do the login
    if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

 //   if(Auth::attempt(['Email' => $input['email'], 'Password' =>$input['password'], 'ArchivedOn' => null])){

        //return redirect()->intended('devices');
            return redirect()->intended('devices');

    } else {

        $err = 'Login Failed Please check credentials and try again.';

        return view('welcome', compact('err'));
    }

}
```

The `Auth::attempt` appears to always return false as it always re-directs to the welcome page with the error message I specified.

I expectect I am missing something obvious but I thought I would ask for a fresh pair of eyes on this as I can't see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your userdata should be:-

```
$userdata = array(
   'Email'     => $input['email'],
   'password'  => $input['password']
);
```

**Note**: You need to write Password 's p character in small letter. You can  change email with Email or Username whatever name you want but password must be 'password'.

Check [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication) for more detail.

Comment: God I knew it would be something silly thanks Ravi that worked